# compile function in directive not evaluating correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive called validate that transcludes a form and automatically validates the form based on the built in angular input validation directives.  Part of this directive's job is to loop through the child inputs on the form and add appropriate tooltips for data validation.  This takes place in the compile portion of the directive.  The problem is that the data bindings I set  in the compile function don't evaluate in html.  For example

```
app.directive('validate', ["$timeout", "$compile", "gsap", function ($timeout, $compile, gsap) {
    return {
        scope: {
            name: "@"
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.validate = {};
        },
        template: '<form name="{{name}}" ng-transclude></form>',
        transclude: true,
        compile: function compile(element, attr) {

            //wrap this in a timeout function and wait for children to be available
            //Have also tried this in the postLink function to the same result

            $timeout(function () {
                var selective = element.find('.validate');

                if (selective.length > 0) {
                    $.each(selective, function (k, v) {
                        v.attr({
                            "tooltip": '{{validate.' + $(v).attr("name") + '}}',
                                "tooltip-trigger": '{{{true: "invalid", false: "valid"}[{{name}}.' + $(v).attr("name") + '.$invalid]}}'
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    $.each(element.find('input'), function (k, v) {
                        $(v).attr({
                            "tooltip": '{{validate.' + $(v).attr("name") + '}}',
                                "tooltip-trigger": '{{{true: "invalid", false: "valid"}[{{name}}.' + $(v).attr("name") + '.$invalid]}}'
                        });
                    });
                }
            });

            return {

                post: function postLink(scope, elem, attr, controller) {


                    //...a whole bunch of validation code, all works fine...
                    //should compile with attributes and resolved databindings

                    $compile(scope, elem, attr, controller);
                }
            };
        }

    };
}]);
```

This evaluates to the following in my DOM

```
<input ng-model="username" type="email" placeholder="Username" name="username" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="2" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-email ng-valid-minlength" required="required" tooltip="{{validate.username}}" tooltip-trigger="{{{true: &quot;invalid&quot;, false: &quot;valid&quot;}[{{name}}.username.$invalid]}}">
```

As you can see, the attributes are set, but the data bindings are not evaluating as i would expect them to

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  For anyone curious, the compile function syntax is `$compile(elem)(scope)`  I forgot the scope to compile against.